# how to bypass mozilla confirm alert box

Tags: php, javascript

When i try to go to last visited page on my website in mozilla i get this message "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier". Can anyone tell me how to bypass this. This is so frustrating. i have used php on my website

Comment: i can't use use GET method, i don't values to be shown in the URL and as for location header the it is not that page is redirecting itself, if a user presses the backspace or the "go back" link present on the browser,then this message comes. Sorry if i was not specific.

Comment: Note that there's a difference between actions that *shouldn't* be repeatable (like payments and order confirmations) and actions that *should* (like searches). Actions which change the state of the server should be POST actions, these are the ones protected by that popup. Actions which just GET information don't trigger the alert

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Redirect user to the same page or to another page so it won't show again

```
 header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

However, `PHP_SELF` is dangerous, please use current page name instead of it.

Comment: PHP_SELF is dangerous, please use current page name instead of it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `method="get"` in your forms, when it's not necessary to use `"post"`. the POST method should be used to submit sensitive / huge number of data.

Or, if your form doesn't have to show up again, redirect the page using the `Location` header, after submitting the POST form.

Answer (score 0):

After processing a POST request, redirect to another page (using `GET`). In that way, the browser won't prompt for it anymore. Note that your application must support it.

```
header('Location: /your/page.php');
```

Alternatively, if a `POST` request is not necessary, use `method="get"` in your `<form>` elements.